# Como mostrar una imagen de folder local a un "ImageView"

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

Estoy tratando de mostar una imagen que esta alamacenada en el folder "drawable" y estoy usando'setImageURI' pero por alguna razon que desconosco no me esta funcionando el codigo.

La information que estoy cargando en el app es de un archivo json en el cual tengo el nombre, la locacion y la direccion de la image.

para obtener la direccino de la imagen estoy usando el metodo, que me da un string con el la direccion de la image.

> estudiante.getImagen();

Gracias a Julian se que puedo usar: NuevaView.imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ci);
para cargar la imagen, pero seria siempre la misma imagen para todos. Hay alguna forma para cargar la direccion de cada imagen.

Intente usando setImageURI pero no me aparece nada en la palicacion, me salo en blanco la seccion de la image..el archivo json tiene 20 miembros cada uno con su nombre, locacion y una imagine unica asignada a cada quien.

algouna idea como puedo solucionar este problema.

```
String img = estudiante.getImagen();
File imagenArchivo= new  File(img);
NuevaView.imagen.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imagenArchivo));
```

Aqui esta el ImageView que estoy usando

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cc"/>
```

y aqui el codigo para mostrar la imagen

```
 if (vista== null) {
   vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, viewGroup, false);
   NuevaView= new NewView();
   NuevaView.nombre= (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.Nombre);
   NuevaView.locacion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.Locacion);
   NuevaView.imagen = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            vista.setTag(NewView);
        } else
   NewView = (NewView) view.getTag();

        NuevaView.name.setText(estudiante.getNombre());
        NuevaView.location.setText(estudiante.getLocacion()); 
        String img = estudiante.getImagen();
        File imagenArchivo= new  File(img);
        NuevaView.imagen.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imagenArchivo));

            return vista;
    }
        public class NuevaView{
            TextView nombre;
            TextView locacion;
            ImageView imagen;
        }
```

Comment: y poniendole a la getImagen() que devuelva un int y segun el int que ponga el drawable? con un switch, no se si es la mejor forma, pero puede funcionar

Comment: Que valor tiene @Pedro estudiante.getImagen() si usas setImageResource deberia ser un int pero si deseas descargar ese valor sería string.

Comment: creo que @Jorgesys quiere que le muestres un ejemplo del Json que usas para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: @Jorgesys es un string...estoy un poco confundido...public String getImagen() { return imagen; }  public void setImagen(String imagen) { this.imagen = imagen; } muchas gracias por ayudarme

Comment: Puedes realizar debugging y revisar que valor se tiene en la variable imagen?  tal vez es una url de forma http//imagen... @Pedro

Comment: @Jorgesys me aparecio el error que dice....resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: file:///%40assets/ci.jpg en mi archivo json tengo la seccion de images: "imagen": "@drawable/ci"

Comment: Sucede que la cadena en realidad es una Uri entonces esta debe convertirse a Uri pero se usa otro método, agregué respuesta. @Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cadena que recibes como imagen del `json` es:

```
 "@drawable/ci"
```

que hace referencia a una imagen de nombre `ci` que se encuentra dentro del folder `/drawable`, es muy importante que esta imagen o las imágenes que indique el feed como imagen dentro de `"@drawable/"` deben existir en el proyecto.

Para cargar la imagen, se debe realizar de esta forma, primeramente recuerda que para acceder a un recurso del proyecto en el directorio `/drawable`, se puede realizar mediante esta ruta:

```
"android.resource://<PAQUETE DE APLICACION>/drawable/"
```

Por lo tanto esta sería la forma adecuada de cargar la imagen:

```
String img = estudiante.getImagen();
//Crea ruta de la imagen.
img = img.replace("@drawable/", "android.resource://"+ getPackageName() +"/drawable/");
//Obtiene la uri de la imagen.
Uri uriImagen = Uri.parse(img);
//Agrega imagen al ImageView.
NuevaView.imagen.setImageURI(uriImagen);
```

Comment: Hermano muchas gracias...estube batallando demasiado para lograr mostar la image...muchas gracas una vez...ya funcinoa la app como debe de ser y se puede ver la image! Eres grande

Comment: Un placer @Pedro, solo recuerda que al agregar preguntas, trata de ser especifico aportar información y obtendrás varias respuestas valiosas. Crea tus preguntas en base a [ask], saludos!.